# How to combine spring boot oauth2 with custom user accounts?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

This here is my first post to stack overflow (after plenty of reading), so I'm going to do my best to get it right. I've been looking up this problem for weeks and haven't found an answer to it, but I happily admit that there's a possibility I'm not looking up the right terms. I'm self-taught, so I sometimes miss things.

I have a Spring Boot application with custom user accounts stored in a postgres database. I would like to add OAuth2 support to that application. I have been able to successfully add OAuth2 login, but I would like to intercept that OAuth2 user information and use it to access one of my custom user accounts.

User signs into Github OAuth -> Server accesses OAuth details and retrieves matching user account info from my user database.

My ideal workflow would be to intercept the OAuth2 details and retrieve the custom info from my DB before the user is redirected to the protected page or back to the index.

Hopefully I managed to include all of the relevant code snippets below. In case I missed anything, the full project can be seen on this here github repository: https://github.com/Ahimsaka/shorturl2.

**Web Security Config**

```
package com.github.ahimsaka.shorturl.security;

import com.github.ahimsaka.shorturl.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/url", "/user/registration", "/user/resetPassword", "/user/savePassword", "login/oauth2/code/github")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user").hasAnyAuthority("USER", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user/registration", "/u/*", "/login*", "/forgotPassword",
                        "/user/resetPassword", "user/savePassword").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/url").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/delete/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "USER")
                .antMatchers("/admin").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/u/*").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/user", true)
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

**Index With Github Login Link**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http:/www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
Index
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
    Welcome <b><span sec:authentication="name">Username</span></b>
    &nbsp;
    <i><span sec:authentication="principal.authorities">Roles</span></i>
    <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
</div>
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated() == false">
    <a href="/login"><input type="button" value="Login" /></a>
    With GitHub: <a href="/oauth2/authorization/github">click here</a>
</div>
<div align="center">
    <h1>Shorten My URL</h1>
    <br />
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/url}"
          method="post">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="10">
            <tr>
                <td>URL:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="url"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><button type="submit">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ADMIN')"><a href="/admin">Admin</a></div>
    <div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('USER')"><a href="/user">User</a></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Registration Controller - Where I would LIKE the Magic to Happen**

```
package com.github.ahimsaka.shorturl.controller;

import com.github.ahimsaka.shorturl.dto.PasswordDto;
import com.github.ahimsaka.shorturl.dto.UserDto;
import com.github.ahimsaka.shorturl.entity.User;
import com.github.ahimsaka.shorturl.entity.VerificationToken;
import com.github.ahimsaka.shorturl.exception.UserAlreadyExistException;
import com.github.ahimsaka.shorturl.exception.UserNotFoundException;
import com.github.ahimsaka.shorturl.exception.util.GenericResponse;
import com.github.ahimsaka.shorturl.registration.OnRegistrationCompleteEvent;
import com.github.ahimsaka.shorturl.service.UserSecurityService;
import com.github.ahimsaka.shorturl.service.UserService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.OAuth2User;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.result.view.RedirectView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

@RestController
public class RegistrationController {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RegistrationController.class);
    private UserService userService;
    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;
    private MessageSource messages;
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;
    private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;

    RegistrationController(UserService userService, ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher,
                           MessageSource messages, JavaMailSender mailSender, UserSecurityService userSecurityService) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.messages = messages;
        this.applicationEventPublisher = applicationEventPublisher;
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
        this.userSecurityService = userSecurityService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/user/registration")
    public ModelAndView showRegistrationForm() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("registration");
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();

        modelAndView.getModel().put("user", userDto);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @PostMapping("/user/registration")
    public ModelAndView registerUserAccount(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid UserDto userDto,
                                            HttpServletRequest request, Errors errors) {

        try {
            User registered = userService.registerNewUserAccount(userDto);

            String appUrl = request.getContextPath();
            applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new OnRegistrationCompleteEvent(registered, request.getLocale(), appUrl));

        } catch (UserAlreadyExistException uaeEx) {

            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("registration", "user", userDto);
            mav.addObject("message", "An account for that username/email already exists.");
            return mav;
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            return new ModelAndView("emailError", "user", userDto);
        }

        return new ModelAndView("successRegister", "user", userDto);
    }

    @GetMapping("/registrationConfirm")
    public ModelAndView confirmRegistration(WebRequest request,
                                            @RequestParam("token") String token) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

        Locale locale = request.getLocale();

        VerificationToken verificationToken = userService.getVerificationToken(token);

        if (verificationToken == null) {
            String message = messages.getMessage("auth.message.invalidToken", null, locale);
            mav.setViewName("badUser");
            mav.getModel().put("message", message);
            return mav;
        }

        User user = verificationToken.getUser();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        if ((verificationToken.getExpiryDate().getTime() - cal.getTime().getTime()) <= 0) {
            String messageValue = messages.getMessage("auth.message.expired", null, locale);
            mav.setViewName("badUser");
            mav.getModel().put("message", messageValue);
            mav.getModel().put("token", token);
            mav.getModel().put("expired", true);
            return mav;

        }

        user.setEnabled(true);
        userService.saveRegisteredUser(user);;
        mav.setViewName("login");
        mav.getModel().put("message", messages.getMessage("message.accountVerified", null, locale));
        return mav;
    }

    @GetMapping("/user/resendRegistrationToken")
    public GenericResponse resendRegistrationToken(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                   @RequestParam("token") String existingToken) {
        VerificationToken newToken = userService.generateNewVerificationToken(existingToken);

        User user = userService.getUser(newToken.getToken());

        SimpleMailMessage email = constructResendVerificationTokenEmail(getAppUrl(request), request.getLocale(), newToken, user);
        mailSender.send(email);

        return new GenericResponse(messages.getMessage("message.resendToken", null, request.getLocale()));
    }

    @PostMapping("/user/resetPassword")
    public ModelAndView resetPassword(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("email") String userEmail) {

        User user = userService.findByUsername(userEmail);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException();
        }
        String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        userService.createPasswordResetTokenForUser(user, token);

        mailSender.send(constructResetTokenEmail(getAppUrl(request), request.getLocale(), token, user));
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("login");
        mav.getModel().put("message", messages.getMessage("message.resetPasswordEmail", null, request.getLocale()));
        return mav;
    }

    @GetMapping("/user/changePassword")
    public ModelAndView showChangePasswordPage(Locale locale, @RequestParam("token") String token) {

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

        String result = userSecurityService.validatePasswordResetToken(token);

        if (result != null) {
            String message = messages.getMessage("auth.message." + result, null, locale);
            mav.getModel().put("message", message);
            mav.setViewName("login");
        } else {
            mav.getModel().put("password", new PasswordDto());
            mav.getModel().put("token", token);
            mav.setViewName("updatePassword");
        }
        return mav;
    }

    @PostMapping("/user/savePassword")
    public ModelAndView savePassword(HttpServletRequest request,
                                     @ModelAttribute("password") @Valid PasswordDto passwordDto) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        String result = userSecurityService.validatePasswordResetToken(passwordDto.getToken());

        if (result != null) {
            mav.setViewName("updatePassword");
            mav.getModel().put("message", messages.getMessage("auth.message." + result, null, request.getLocale()));
            return mav;
        }

        Optional user = userService.getUserByPasswordResetToken(passwordDto.getToken());

        if (user.isPresent()) {
            userService.changeUserPassword((User) user.get(), passwordDto.getNewPassword(), passwordDto.getToken());
            mav.setViewName("login");
            mav.getModel().put("message", messages.getMessage("message.resetPasswordSuc", null, request.getLocale()));
        } else {
            mav.setViewName("updatePassword");
            mav.getModel().put("message", messages.getMessage("auth.message.invalid", null, request.getLocale()));
        }
        return mav;
    }

    @GetMapping("/forgotPassword")
    private ModelAndView forgotPasswordPage() {
        return new ModelAndView("forgotPassword");
    }

    @GetMapping("login/oauth2/code/github")
    // This does nothing but I haven't removed it yet.
    private ModelAndView oauthUserSignIn(HttpServletRequest request, Authentication authentication) {
        return new ModelAndView("user");

    }


    //   NON API

    private SimpleMailMessage constructResendVerificationTokenEmail (String contextPath, Locale locale, VerificationToken newToken, User user){
        String url = contextPath + "/registrationConfirm?token=" + newToken.getToken();
        String message = messages.getMessage("message.resendToken", null, locale);
        return constructEmail("Resend Registration Token", message + " \r\n" + url, user);
    }

    private SimpleMailMessage constructResetTokenEmail(String contextPath, Locale locale, String token, User user) {
        String url = contextPath + "/user/changePassword?token=" + token;
        String message = messages.getMessage("message.resetPassword", null, locale);
        return constructEmail("Reset Password", message + " \r\n" + url, user);
    }

    private SimpleMailMessage constructEmail(String subject, String body, User user) {
        SimpleMailMessage email = new SimpleMailMessage();
        email.setSubject(subject);
        email.setText(body);
        email.setTo(user.getUsername());
        return email;
    }

    private String getAppUrl(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "http://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath();
    }



}
```

Comment: have you been able to solve it?